# Push notification on pressed button Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to send a notification on the screen when the "Save Button" is pressed.

It's very simple, with no FireBase, no Internet...Just a simple notification on the screen that says "Completed".

I would like to customize it as much as possible: position on the screen, shape, color...

I found the `SnackBar` but isn't what I'm looking for.
This is my first time dealing with notifications so I know a few things...
I read that I need a `NotificationListener`, but currently, this notification must spawn `onTap` so I don't think I need of something that hears for all the time... It's a waste of resources.

Edit, pubspecs.yaml :

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.17.4
  circular_profile_avatar: ^1.0.6
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+3
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.5
  fluttertoast: ^5.0.1


  provider: ^4.0.5

  uuid: ^2.0.4 
  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.6.6+1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0

  intl: ^0.16.1


 dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fluttertoast` [flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast) package.

Add the dependency -

**pubspec.yaml**

```
fluttertoast: ^6.0.0
```

Then import the required libraries, wherever needed -

```
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
```

Initialize FlutterToast -

```
FlutterToast flutterToast;

@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterToast = FlutterToast(context);
}
```

Then you create you own custom toast and method to invoke the toast and on your button `onPressed` callback you can call `_showToast()` (it is just a wrapper created to handle toast container creation and invocation) that will trigger the toast notification something like this-

```
_showToast() {
    Widget toast = Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 12.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        ),
        child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
            Icon(Icons.check),
            SizedBox(
            width: 12.0,
            ),
            Text("This is a Custom Toast"),
        ],
        ),
    );


    flutterToast.showToast(
        child: toast,
        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
        toastDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
}
```

This will popup a toast message base on the parameters you provide.

Here's the sample code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

void main() {
  //Run the App Widget
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Demo App",
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  FlutterToast flutterToast;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flutterToast = FlutterToast(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Demo Notification"),
      ),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
        onPressed: () {
          _showToast();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  _showToast() {
    Widget toast = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 12.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.check),
          SizedBox(
            width: 12.0,
          ),
          Text("This is a Custom Toast"),
        ],
      ),
    );

    flutterToast.showToast(
      child: toast,
      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      toastDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output-**

[image: Output]

You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/FlutterToast).

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: I had this error : The name of the given podspec `FlutterToast` doesn't match the expected one `fluttertoast`. I checked the yaml file and I wrote the right dependency, I also imported the package within my project...Don't know what to do...

Comment: Can you post your pubspec.yaml, make sure the dependency name is 'fluttertoast' and not 'FlutterToast'.

Comment: fluttertoast: ^5.0.1 , copy-paste from .yaml

Comment: I believe there is an issue with fluttertoast on ios, https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/188

Comment: Nice, thank you...So the question is still opened? ahahahah

Comment: What a shame, I loved that animation

Comment: There has been updates to the ios library in the package yesterday may be that's causing the issue, hopefully it will be resolved soon.

Comment: For now can you try with version 4.0.0 'fluttertoast: 4.0.0'

Comment: the 4.0.0 is good but "getter 'FlutterToast' isn't defined for the class..." an other bug? I added dependencies and imported the file

Comment: How did you give it the rounded border?

Comment: That's the default styling for the toast.

Comment: They have released the version 6.0.0 for flutter toast and there are significant updates, you can check if it works on IOS now. fluttertoast: ^6.0.0, I have updated answer with new version and code samples.